# Sending Notification to User when Folder is shared with them

Tags: lightning

I would like to send an email to the user that the folder is being shared with.

I have done some research and have found that Triggering custom code or automations specifically when a folder is shared is not supported by Salesforce. Also triggers cannot be written on the sharing event itself.

Is there any workaround or similar function that could help me with my problem?

I am new to the Salesforce community and any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). What kind of folder are you asking about? Two common "types" of folders are documents/files or reports/dashboards. Aside from that, when asking a question it's a good idea to include additional context in terms of what you're trying to accomplish  - see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank you for the information I will definitely take some time to look through the links you have provided. To answer your question I am referring to reports/dashboards. I want users to receive a notification/email that they now have access to a folder of reports or dashboards that they previously did not have access to.

Comment: Vote for this [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdoa2UAB/share-report-folder-object-visibility).  An ugly workaround is to write a batch job that tracks what folders are visible to the user, make a note of it and then see if more folders are available on the next job run. In our opinion, the folder-based approach is not very useful to the potential consumer of reports/dashboards. They want to know what "new" reports/dashboards are available to them and what's in them. That calls for some sort of training or at least more explanation than "here's a folder".

Comment: If you are sharing folder manually, there might be no options to track it but when you are sharing it via REST API, then you can add a code for sending email using Messaging.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a REST API to share the folder (from BTS), then you can add a Messaging Service mail or make an another callout to another system within the same REST API.

Manually when it is shared, there wouldnt be any option. Maybe try to enforce a REST API Callout if the sharing of folder is related to any particular record.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_folders_shares.htm

Check out the above link for REST API folder share.

Comment: The folders are not related to any particular record and we will not be using any REST API to share the folder. Manually sharing is the intent, but I appreciate the option and information you have provided.

Comment: You may have to internally invoke REST API callout, may be as a batch class callout.